# Get the desktop/viewport of a window in enlightenment?

Tags: xorg, window, x-server, enlightenment, wmctrl

Okay, so, given a XID of a window I need to get its desktop or viewport as well as the currently active one. Enlightenment does not seem to properly respond to wmctrl which leads to:

```
***@note:~ > wmctrl -lG
0x01e00002 -1 21   395  310  146  note Conky (note) # it places conkey wndows on -1 for some reason?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0x01c00002 -1 65   655  230  158  note Conky (note)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0x01a00002 -1 25   215  230  182  note Conky (note)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0x01800002 -1 25   550  310  110  note Conky (note)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0x01600002 -1 685  145  230  120  note Conky (note)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0x01400002 -1 1120 245  280  206  note Conky (note)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0x01200002 -1 1095 35   230  186  note Conky (note)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0x01000002 -1 1145 470  250  266  note Conky (note)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0x00c00002 -1 40   34   230  182  note Conky (note)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0x00e00029  0 0    0    1440 900  note ~ : bash – Konsole # desktop 2, fullscreen                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0x03a00060  0 505  231  899  642  note Downloads – 'Dolphin' # destkop 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
0x0480001a  0 206  222  958  526  note Lifelover - Kärlek - becksvart melankoli #desk 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x034000e6  0 116  32   984  767  note clemctrl – Kate #desk 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
0x02c01b78  0 309  314  549  520  note ************* # desk 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
0x04e00062  0 104  31   990  619  note XChat: *** @ Free / #*** (+Ccnt) #desk 1                                                                                                                                                                                                          
0x05c00112  0 22   35   1396 834  note StarCraft on Reddit - Chromium #desk 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0x02c0f292  0 453  356  549  520  note *** #desk 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
0x02c000c0  0 860  216  557  645  note Buddy List # desk 1
```

As can be seen, all windows are on desk 0 in wmctrl except conky windows. Furthermore the geometry-viewport trick also doesn't seem to work that works in some wm's, are there any other tricks to get on which viewport/desktop a window is? There has to be *some* way to get it right?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is enlightenment doesn't handle this properly.

The reason is enlightenment is smarter and can do more then x11 expects it to, for instance it is possible to change monitor 1 to virtual desktop (viewport) 3 and leave monitor 2 on virtual desktop 1. At this point most tools such as wmctrl get very confused because they believe the same virtual desktop should be shared across all monitors.

Because enlightenment does this it stores most of this state on its own it is possible to query some of it with the enlightenment_remote tool, but it is currently pretty limited but maybe you could modify it to provide the info you are looking for.